# 'Expression result unused' AND 'More % than data arguments' warnings

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsstring

I laughed when I saw these two errors beside each other earlier, but now its annoying me because they won't go away!

I am setting the text of a UITextView, and I have 12 arguments being included into the string. If you look at the image below, it is telling me that on one of my "%i's", 'More % conversions than data arguments', but then on the argument line, it tells me that on one of my arguments, "Expression result unused".

I have tried rewriting the whole line, and editing the layout and arrangement of the arguments, no joy.

All of the arguments below are integers, hence the %i's

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last sentence:

```
intValue]], totalZombieKills, totalFlyingZombieKills;
```

It should be

```
intValue], totalZombieKills, totalFlyingZombieKills];
```

Comment: Wow thanks! I definitely need to get some sleep!

Answer (score 1):

Seems you have to move closing square bracket from "[[scoreArray objectAtIndex:9] intValue]]" to end of line just after "totalFlyingZombieKills" =)

PS: Why not printing to string in loop?

Comment: Thanks. I'm not printing it in a loop because this is only one small part of the string. while it would make the code smaller, it would make it more complicated and harder to understand